# Directly seed CPython's Mersenne Twister

Tags: python, cpython

The underlying PRNG of CPython's implementation of the `random` standard module is a Mersenne Twister implemented in `Modules/_randommodule.c`. Reading the source code it seems that calling `random.seed` will first call [`init_by_array`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3c05d7efca8d23bf39bc2640297ba2598899f3/Modules/_randommodule.c#L171-L196) defined in that source file which in turn calls [`init_genrand`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3c05d7efca8d23bf39bc2640297ba2598899f3/Modules/_randommodule.c#L148-L166). I was wondering if there is some way to circumvent the call to `init_by_array` and, from Python code, directly call `init_genrand` with a specific seed (or alternatively, given a desired seed, construct a Python object that can be passed to `random.seed` such that `init_genrand` will be called with that seed).

My motivation for this is that I would like to test my own Mersenne Twister implementation by comparing its output to that of `random.getrandbits` after providing a specific seed.

Comment: Why not provide a seed to `random.seed` but seed your implementation with whatever `init_genrand` receives for that argument?

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing that. I think there's not way to directly pass a seed through to `init_genrand`.

Comment: Sounds like a self-answer is in order.